# server client android application vs client only

Tags: android, sockets, client

Hi i'm relatively new to android programming and am trying to do the following. I want to create a messaging system in which immediate response is not (at least for now necessary). I am completely new to networking / socket programming but have followed this:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

and have kinda got my head around it.

I have the following question with regards to best practice.

What are the advantages/disadvantages of method A and B.

Method A:
Have a server and client running on the app.

Method B:
Have a client running on the app and pinging the server every minute for data.

Apart from the obvious that Method B doesn't allow real time which is better suggested? Does a server application take too much memory / CPU / battery etc? I know a lot of IM apps exist, how do they work?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you can have some notification mechanism to tell your client app about the incoming data from the server, instead of pinging it every min

Comment: But wouldn't that notification mechanism require the app to be running a server listening to a specific port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use push notifications?
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: ok so I've read quite a bit about this, seems kinda complicated for first time but will give it a try. Hope it works out, definately seems like what I need though which is a good thing. Just need to ride that learning curve. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Google Cloud Messaging but last time I checked you needed a dedicated server to install it. Or Am i wrong? I only had a shared server so:

method A: the difficult part, considering its a mobile device, would be to keep the connection alive when your phone changes IP (another wifi network for example) and

method B: you could make small simple messages in order to check if there is something new and update in that case. My app sent around 500 bytes every 30 seconds and I didnt have any battery related problems. It also didnt slow the phone down.